# Spark Dataframe : Set column values if an conditional row is encountered

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to manipulate values of a row based on the value condition of other rows.

Scenario : If any row has a (`KEY=111 & IND=Yes`), then need to set the `KEY` value as "999" for only rows having `KEY=202`.
And if this row is not present, then we should not set anything.

Sample Input:

```
val rowvalues = List(List("111", "Yes", "2016-11-15T00:00:00.000"), List("111", "No", "2016-12-01T00:00:00.000"),
  List("202", "NA", "2016-12-01T00:00:00.000"), List("202", "NA", "2016-11-15T00:00:00.000"),
  List("303", "Yes", "2016-12-01T00:00:00.000"), List("303", "NA", "2016-11-15T00:00:00.000"))
  .map(row => (row(0), row(1), row(2)))

val df = rowvalues.toDF("KEY", "IND", "DATE")

df.show(false)

+---+---+-----------------------+
|KEY|IND|DATE                   |
+---+---+-----------------------+
|111|Yes|2016-11-15T00:00:00.000|-----> Condition met as KEY=111 & IND=Yes
|111|No |2016-12-01T00:00:00.000|
|202|NA |2016-12-01T00:00:00.000|-----> Set KEY=999
|202|NA |2016-11-15T00:00:00.000|-----> Set KEY=999
|303|Yes|2016-12-01T00:00:00.000|
|303|NA |2016-11-15T00:00:00.000|
+---+---+-----------------------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+---+---+-----------------------+
|KEY|IND|DATE                   |
+---+---+-----------------------+
|111|Yes|2016-11-15T00:00:00.000|
|111|No |2016-12-01T00:00:00.000|
|999|NA |2016-12-01T00:00:00.000|*
|999|NA |2016-11-15T00:00:00.000|*
|303|Yes|2016-12-01T00:00:00.000|
|303|NA |2016-11-15T00:00:00.000|
+---+---+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count the number of rows that match the condition given and use an `if-else` statement. `when` and `otherwise` can be used when replacing 202 to 999.

```
val cond = df.filter($"KEY" === 111  && $"IND" === "Yes").count() > 0

val df2 = if(cond) {
  df.withColumn("KEY", when($"KEY" === 202, 999).otherwise($"KEY"))
} else {
  df
}
```

Result:

```
+---+---+-----------------------+
|KEY|IND|DATE                   |
+---+---+-----------------------+
|111|Yes|2016-11-15T00:00:00.000|
|111|No |2016-12-01T00:00:00.000|
|999|NA |2016-12-01T00:00:00.000|
|999|NA |2016-11-15T00:00:00.000|
|303|Yes|2016-12-01T00:00:00.000|
|303|NA |2016-11-15T00:00:00.000|
+---+---+-----------------------+
```